# State of child components in React

Tags: reactjs

Should child components never have a state in React? I understand that state should be maintained by the "wrapper container" or parent container and it should have unidirectional flow. I have started with React and have a header container with upto 10 child components.

Let's say one of the child component is a Form with a submit button that can be enabled or disabled.

Should this child component not be able to have a constructor with state initialized for the button and be able to directly manipulate it or is it important that I maintain states as minute as this in the wrapper container "only"?

Answer (score 1):

You should let the parent container manage the state of forms. I usually attach an onChange listener to each input and then when the submit button is clicked I call a function in the parent component to submit the value contained in the state for my form inputs. The form should only render inputs and do nothing else,  basically a dumb component.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of React is providing a **component system** to front-end. It does **not** specify/enforce how state flow. People generally prefer state-less components because it is easier to share and distribute. However, front-end component can never be **fully** state-less + declarative.

In my opinion, you should feel free to use `this.state` to manage local state when you feel appropriate.

Comment: That's a relief to know :)